# book on calabi yau manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, gt.geometric-topology

hi,

does anybody know a good book on calabi yau manifolds (i am a beginner) ?
thanks in advance

lois

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on how much of a beginner you are, you could begin by reading Barth-Hulek-Peters-Van de Ven paying particular attention to the section on K3 surfaces (which are 2-(complex)-dimensional Calabi-Yaus):

http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-540-00832-3

For an overview, you could try:

http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Calabi-Yau_manifold

Other good and possibly relevant books include:

Besse, Arthur L. (1987), Einstein manifolds, Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete (3), 10, Berlin, New York: Springer-Verlag,

Gross, M.; Huybrechts, D.; Joyce, Dominic (2003), Calabi–Yau manifolds and related geometries, Universitext, Berlin, New York: Springer-Verlag,

Hübsch, Tristan (1994), Calabi–Yau Manifolds: a Bestiary for Physicists, Singapore, New York: World Scientific.

Answer (score 6):

I would also add the following book:

[Dominic Joyce, Compact Manifolds with Special Holonomy](http://books.google.ca/books?id=c3P-YUD8GZQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=dominic+joyce+compact+manifolds&hl=en&ei=oKq2TpXuEMjq0gGH3OXRBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

The early parts of the book include an introduction to the *Riemannian geometry* of Calabi-Yau manifolds. It also includes a proof of the Calabi conjecture.